# "Troubleshooting Block Production Issue After Switching to ECDSA Signature Scheme in Substrate-based Blockchain"

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node, consensus

I've transitioned the signature scheme to ECDSA on a Substrate-based chain, following Moonbeam's approach. However, it's worth noting that Moonbeam utilizes Aura for block production, whereas Substrate typically relies on BABE for this purpose. Despite successful compilation, I'm encountering an issue where the blockchain fails to produce any blocks upon startup. I'm seeking guidance to identify and resolve the underlying cause of this problem. Can anyone provide assistance?